# Building a Console app (just like TwitterSearch.UI.Console) sample

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm working on a project that has client and server side.
And I'm writing a "pre-check-in" tool that will validate a lot of our communication between client and server.

I already have unit tests on both sides, now i really want to test the integration between both.

Like a real client connection to the server and vice-versa.

I'm trying to see how "TwitterSearch.UI.Console" works, as I think that twill be a great starting point for me, but after spending some time fighting it, I thought that maybe it's better to ask the pros in here.

I'm using the latest version from here:
https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials

paired with latest binaries.

Right now this is the output debug spill:

```
mvx: Diagnostic:   0.01 Setup: PlatformServices start
mvx: Diagnostic:   0.02 Setup: MvvmCross settings start
mvx: Diagnostic:   0.02 Setup: Singleton Cache start
mvx: Diagnostic:   0.02 Setup: Bootstrap actions
mvx: Diagnostic:   0.05 Setup: StringToTypeParser start
mvx: Diagnostic:   0.05 Setup: ViewModelFramework start
mvx: Diagnostic:   0.05 Setup: PluginManagerFramework start
mvx: Diagnostic:   0.06 Setup: App start
mvx: Diagnostic:   0.07 Loading plugin assembly: Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.Wpf
'TwitterSearch.UI.Console.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\fileZ\projZ\samples\MvvmCross-Tutorials\Sample - TwitterSearch\TwitterSearch.UI.Console\bin\Debug\TwitterSearch.Core.dll', Symbols loaded.
'TwitterSearch.UI.Console.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\fileZ\projZ\samples\MvvmCross-Tutorials\Sample - TwitterSearch\TwitterSearch.UI.Console\bin\Debug\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.dll', Symbols loaded.
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException' occurred in Cirrious.CrossCore.dll
```

And in the exception details, looks like the plugin manager is resolving the name of the assembly wrong?

He is trying to load `Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.Wpf`, and the one referenced by the .Console app is `Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.Console`.

Here are more details from the exception:

```
Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.Wpf' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=Cirrious.CrossCore
  StackTrace:
       at Cirrious.CrossCore.Plugins.MvxPluginManager.ExceptionWrappedLoadPlugin(Type toLoad) in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\CrossCore\Cirrious.CrossCore\Plugins\MvxPluginManager.cs:line 136
       at Cirrious.CrossCore.Plugins.MvxPluginManager.EnsurePlatformAdaptionLoaded[T]() in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\CrossCore\Cirrious.CrossCore\Plugins\MvxPluginManager.cs:line 87
       at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.PluginLoader.EnsureLoaded() in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Plugins\Cirrious\Visibility\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility\PluginLoader.cs:line 23
       at TwitterSearch.Core.TwitterSearchApp.InitialisePlugIns() in c:\fileZ\projZ\samples\MvvmCross-Tutorials\Sample - TwitterSearch\TwitterSearch.Core\TwitterSearchApp.cs:line 33
       at TwitterSearch.Core.TwitterSearchApp..ctor() in c:\fileZ\projZ\samples\MvvmCross-Tutorials\Sample - TwitterSearch\TwitterSearch.Core\TwitterSearchApp.cs:line 15
       at TwitterSearch.UI.Console.Setup.CreateApp() in c:\fileZ\projZ\samples\MvvmCross-Tutorials\Sample - TwitterSearch\TwitterSearch.UI.Console\Setup.cs:line 16
       at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Platform.MvxSetup.CreateAndInitializeApp(IMvxPluginManager pluginManager) in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross\Platform\MvxSetup.cs:line 272
       at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Platform.MvxSetup.InitializeApp(IMvxPluginManager pluginManager) in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross\Platform\MvxSetup.cs:line 265
       at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Platform.MvxSetup.InitializeSecondary() in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross\Platform\MvxSetup.cs:line 77
       at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Platform.MvxSetup.Initialize() in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross\Platform\MvxSetup.cs:line 36
       at TwitterSearch.UI.Console.Program.Run() in c:\fileZ\projZ\samples\MvvmCross-Tutorials\Sample - TwitterSearch\TwitterSearch.UI.Console\Program.cs:line 21
       at TwitterSearch.UI.Console.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\fileZ\projZ\samples\MvvmCross-Tutorials\Sample - TwitterSearch\TwitterSearch.UI.Console\Program.cs:line 14
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
       HResult=-2147024894
       Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.Wpf' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
       Source=mscorlib
       FileName=Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.Wpf
       FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = LAGOA\Sergio
LOG: DisplayName = Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.Wpf
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.Wpf | Domain ID: 1
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/fileZ/projZ/samples/MvvmCross-Tutorials/Sample - TwitterSearch/TwitterSearch.UI.Console/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : Cirrious.CrossCore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e16445fd9b451819.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\fileZ\projZ\samples\MvvmCross-Tutorials\Sample - TwitterSearch\TwitterSearch.UI.Console\bin\Debug\TwitterSearch.UI.Console.vshost.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/fileZ/projZ/samples/MvvmCross-Tutorials/Sample - TwitterSearch/TwitterSearch.UI.Console/bin/Debug/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.Wpf.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/fileZ/projZ/samples/MvvmCross-Tutorials/Sample - TwitterSearch/TwitterSearch.UI.Console/bin/Debug/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.Wpf/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.Wpf.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/fileZ/projZ/samples/MvvmCross-Tutorials/Sample - TwitterSearch/TwitterSearch.UI.Console/bin/Debug/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.Wpf.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/fileZ/projZ/samples/MvvmCross-Tutorials/Sample - TwitterSearch/TwitterSearch.UI.Console/bin/Debug/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.Wpf/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.Wpf.EXE.

       StackTrace:
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
            at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
            at Cirrious.CrossCore.Plugins.MvxFilePluginManager.LoadAssembly(Type toLoad) in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\CrossCore\Cirrious.CrossCore\Plugins\MvxFilePluginManager.cs:line 53
            at Cirrious.CrossCore.Plugins.MvxFilePluginManager.FindPlugin(Type toLoad) in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\CrossCore\Cirrious.CrossCore\Plugins\MvxFilePluginManager.cs:line 31
            at Cirrious.CrossCore.Plugins.MvxPluginManager.ExceptionWrappedLoadPlugin(Type toLoad) in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\CrossCore\Cirrious.CrossCore\Plugins\MvxPluginManager.cs:line 120
       InnerException:
```

Can someone help me figure out if I did something wrong or if the plug in is really trying to load the wrong file?

Thank you,
Sergio

Answer (score 2):

There's a recent change which means `Console` and `Wpf` will both share `Wpf` plugins (as they are both .Net45 plugins).

This was made after https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/pull/395 - it seemed pointless to do this duplication.

This change is released in the current binaries which are tagged `3.0.11-beta1` - we're trying to release 3.0.11 stable with release notes asap (but are fighting Xamarin setup and PCL issues). When we hit stable, then we will (try to) update all the sample projects too. (However, TwitterSearch is sadly now permanently broken as Twitter have deprecated the RSS API that it used).

If you need the previous stable binaries they can be download as `3.0.10` on https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Binaries/releases

As for the value of `Console`, I generally find this limited - I find writing unit tests is a better way forwards rather than writing a Console app. I generally find the Console is too a limited UI experience to use for 'real' apps.

Comment: Thank you Stuart.

But unfortunately that helped get to the next error:

Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\fileZ\projZ\samples\MvvmCross-Tutorials\Sample - TwitterSearch\TwitterSearch.UI.Console\bin\Debug\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.Console.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
  Source=Cirrious.CrossCore

Should it work fine with 3.0.10? Should I use older sample also?

Comment: Another issue is that I was really trying UnitTest, but as I need real connections to the server (httpclient) and Sqlite support to enable the full test of my code, I COULD NOT make it work.

For instance: can't find a way to instantiate a view model that would need:

(IChatService chatService, IMvxMessenger messenger, IDataService dataService, ISettingsService settings)

all above services, when the IDataService for instance, also needs 

(ISQLiteConnectionFactory factory, IMvxMessenger messenger, ISettingsService settings)

Maybe any hint on how to us real iOC container for all?

Comment: Thanks, I was banging my head for this sudden error asking for wpf-plugin. BTW: I use the console app tools to create the initial database for the phones, then they are put in the projects for iPhone and Android. This way I can use the Mvx models and data structures. Of course I could write a unit-test doing the same, but a console app seemed more appropriate.